# pl/sql hierachical data arrangement

Tags: sql, oracle11g, hierarchical

**Table tMain:**

```
+----+-------+---------+
| ID | name  | id_ref  |
+----+-------+---------+
| 1  | amine |      4  |
| .. |       |         |
+----+-------+---------+
```

**Table tTree:**

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| ID |  name  | id_parent |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | root   | null      |
|  2 | child1 | 1         |
|  3 | child2 | 2         |
|  4 | child3 | 3         |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

So I have to tables which i would like to "connect". Table "tMain" contains some data and a foreign key referencing the tTree table (reference to the lowest child item). What I would like is to use one query to get all the data from tMain together with the assembled path from tTree.  It would look like this:

```
+----+-------+--------+---------------------------+
| ID | name  | id_ref |           Path            |
+----+-------+--------+---------------------------+
| 1  | amine |      4 | root/child1/child2/child3 |
| .. |       |        |                           |
+----+-------+--------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Check out the `connect by` operator, or recursive common table expressions. This has been asked many times before. And why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: i do sort of know the connect by operator, but i couldn't come up with a combination where it gave me the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH tree$ AS (
    SELECT T.id, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(name, '/'), '/') AS path
    FROM tTree T
    START WITH id_parent IS NULL
    CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = id_parent
)
SELECT T.id, M.name, M.id_ref, T.path
FROM tMain M
    JOIN tree$ T ON T.id = M.id_ref
;
```

Comment: Please, be aware that depending on the amounts of your data the query might be, performance-wise, suboptimal and that for special cases a better performing query does exist. But that would be a different topic. Other than that, you're welcome. :-)

Comment: well it is indeed quite a lot of data, but I haven't seen any performance issue yet